# Biographical information on Anne Marie Whitney

Tags: ho.history-overview, total-positivity

I am looking for information on the mathematician Anne Marie
Whitney. She wrote a number of significant papers related to total positivity with her thesis adviser Isaac Schoenberg. All I could find on the internet is
https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=36202.

Comment: I think this obituary, if accurate, gives a starting point: https://www.ancestry.com/boards/localities.northam.usa.states.michigan.counties.kalamazoo/24044/mb.ashx

Comment: Here is another link: https://womenbecomingmathematicians.net/db/forties/penn/calloway1949/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is more under her married name, **Anne Calloway** (October 2, 1921, December 27, 2008). Here is a [photograph](https://www.langelands.com/notices/Anne-Calloway). Anne Whitney married her graduate school class mate [Jean Calloway,](https://books.google.nl/books?id=RfXGJBB1HvoC&pg=PA69) who himself became a professor of mathematics (author of this [text book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201008750)). In an interview from 1996, [summarized here](https://books.google.nl/books?id=Sz78C8-PGUQC&pg=PA196#v=onepage&q&f=false), she laments the fact that her marriage ended her career as a mathematician. I guess many of my generation have similar stories of their parents.

[image]

Comment: Wow! You are so good in finding an answer to every single question. You are simply a google-human being.