# Nonnegativity locus of Schur polynomials

Tags: inequalities, symmetric-functions, symmetric-polynomials, schur-functions

Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n \in \mathbb{C}$ be complex numbers that are the zeros of a real polynomial (meaning that the non-real ones come in complex conjugate pairs). Suppose that these numbers are such that
$$
s_\lambda(a_1,\ldots,a_n) \ge 0
$$
for every partition $\lambda = (\lambda_1 \ge \ldots \ge \lambda_n)$, where $s_\lambda$ denotes the [Schur polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_polynomial) associated to $\lambda$. **Do these inequalities imply that $a_i \in \mathbb{R}_+$ for all $i$?**

Here's what I know so far:

- The converse is obvious: if $a_i \in \mathbb{R}_+$ for all $i$, then the sum over Young tableaux formula immediately shows $s_\lambda(a_1,\ldots,a_n) \ge 0$.
- It's enough to show that the $a_i$ are real. Nonnegativity then follows by Descartes' rule of signs upon noting that the elementary symmetric functions $s_{(1,\ldots,1)}$ are, up to alternating signs, the coefficients of the polynomial $\prod_i (x-a_i)$.
- The statement is true and easy to prove for $n = 2$: it's enough to postulate nonnegativity merely for $\lambda = (n,0,\ldots)$, i.e. on the complete homogeneous symmetric polynomials. On these,
  $$
  s_{(n,0,\ldots)}(r e^{i\theta},r e^{-i\theta}) = \frac{(r e^{i\theta}))^{n+1} - (r e^{-i\theta})^{n+1}}{re^{i\theta}-re^{-i\theta}} = r^n \frac{\sin((n+1)\theta)}{\sin(\theta)},
  $$
  which for every nonzero $\theta$ is obviously negative for some $n$, proving the contrapositive statement.
  This suggests that some Fourier analysis may be useful for the general case, or perhaps the [Harish-Chandra-Itzykson-Zuber formula](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/02/08/the-harish-chandra-itzykson-zuber-integral-formula/), but I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: In fact, it's easy to see that already for $n=2$, the nonnegativity of the elementary symmetric functions is not enough: one also needs the discriminant inequality $e_1^2 \ge 4 e_2$ in order to ensure that the roots are real.

Comment: Oops, I misunderstood the question. I am deleting my previous comments. Hope to post a correct answer soon.

Comment: I believe the question is equivalent to Exercise 7.91(e) of *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 2.

Comment: Very interesting @RichardStanley! I'd probably be able to do it myself based on that excellent reference, but I'd also be more than happy to accept your answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to the main question is affirmative. The crucial result is due to M. Aissen, I. J. Schoenberg, and A. Whitney, [*J. Analyse Math.* **2** (1952), 93—103](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02786970). For further details see the solution to Exercise 7.91(e) in *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 2. (For some interesting information on A. Whitney, see [Biographical information on Anne Marie Whitney](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/320906/biographical-information-on-anne-marie-whitney))

Comment: This answer has been an essential ingredient in the proof of the main result of [Asymptotic and catalytic containment of representations of $SU(n)$](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.10899) (see p.5). Thanks again for your help.