# Positive values of Schur polynomials

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, symmetric-polynomials

Recall that for a given partition $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_r)$, its Schur polynomial in $n$-variables is the sum of monomials
$$s_\lambda(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\sum_{T\in\operatorname{SSYT}(\lambda)}\mathbf{x}^T$$
ranging over the set of semi-standard Young tableau $\operatorname{SSYT}(\lambda)$ which are fillings of the Young diagram of $\lambda$ with the numbers $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that the rows are weakly increasing and the columns are strictly increasing, and for such a tableau $T$ with $a_1$ $1$'s, $a_2$ $2$'s and so on, the monomial $\mathbf{x}^T=x_1^{a_1}x_2^{a_2}\cdots x_n^{a_n}$.

**Question:**
Is anything known about the real locus of positive values of $s_\lambda$, i.e.
$$P_n(\lambda)=\left\{(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n \ | \ s_\lambda(a_1,\ldots,a_n)>0\right\}?$$

**Comments:**

The obvious first thing to say here is that $P_n(\lambda)$ always contains the positive orthant $\mathbb{R}^n_{>0}$, but can we say anything more?

Note my question is slightly different from [this related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419823/nonnegativity-locus-of-schur-polynomials); here I am concerned with the positivity locus of a single Schur polynomial (although maybe that wonderful answer is related but I don't quite see how at the time of writing).

For my specific problem, it's enough to assume that the partition is rectangular, i.e. all parts are equal, if that helps.

Any references, remarks, or even keywords for google searches are all warmly welcome.  Thanks :-)

Comment: If you intersect $P_n(\lambda)$ for all partitions $\lambda$ of length at most $n$, then you get exactly the positive orthant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419823/nonnegativity-locus-of-schur-polynomials?rq=1

Comment: @PerAlexandersson yes thanks that seems to be what that answer is saying (which is very interesting) but I'm wondering if we can say anything about the locus for a single polynomial.

Comment: Perhaps it is easier to just look at the Vandermonde determinant; the Schur polynomial is a quotient of Vandermonde determinants, so its enough to look at the numerator.
Also, I think this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98494/irreducibility-of-schur-polynomials which talks about irreducibility of Schur polynomials shows that the question most likely is tricky.